# Complete and sign a network - igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have generated a random network using the Erdos-Renyi game

```
 g1 <- erdos.renyi.game(30, 0.15, type="gnp", directed = F)
```

Of course, this is not a complete nor signed graph. However, I would like to make it a signed graph completing the network saying that for each missing edge (i.e. a 0 in the adjacency matrix), the sign of the edge is -1 and 1 if two vertex are already connected.

Using `g1[,]` I have 1 if two vertex are connected, therefore I was thinking to use:

```
 E(g1)$sign <- ifelse(g1[,]==1, 1, -1)
```

However, I have of course a warning message saying "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".

How can I create the signs in a way that all the present ties are positive (1) and all absent ones negative (-1)?

Thanks for the support

Comment: Convert to the adjacency matrix `A`, then compute `2*A-1`, then convert back.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I did by the end: I have adjusted the adjacency matrix and reconverted to graph object. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: In the future, feel free to post on https://igraph.discourse.group/ for a possibly quicker answer. It is also appreciated if people participate and answer others' questions there.